# Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_open()

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, geoip

all goes well suddenly i dont know why a fatal error occurred can any one please tell me the solution ???

Warning: include(lang.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 59

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'lang.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 59

Warning: include(lang2.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 61

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'lang2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 61

Warning: include_once(inc.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 265

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 265

Fatal error: Call to undefined function geoip_open() in /var/httpdocs/dev52/include.php on line 266

Comment: "operation not permitted" would suggest something's changed permissions on the files you're trying to include (or the directories those files are in).

Comment: i check these file have 777 permissions

Comment: What about the containing directories?

Comment: same 777 for the containing directories also

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you contact your webhost. If everything was working and it suddenly stops working, especially on a widely-used package like phpMyAdmin, it's more than likely someone changed a configuration setting and screwed it up.

If this doesn't help, or if you own the server yourself, try reinstalling phpMyAdmin.

Comment: the thing is that rest thing is working this is in my testing directory the problem occurred i this testing directly only rest all are working

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens with nested includes, check to see if there are any `include();` statements in `lang.php` and if so then include these files directly.